# how to make simple directed graph using d3

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I am trying to create a simple force layout directed-edge graph base on this D3.js example "http://bl.ocks.org/1153292".

There is line where it says `.data(["suit", "licensing", "resolved"])` but I have no clue what that means. I have to admit I don't fully understand the details of it.

I have looked at a few so questions but none was helpful.

I would really appreciate it if

1. sb can tell what ".data(["suit", "licensing", "resolved"])" means.
2. How are arrows added to the end of the edges.

Answer (score 0):

1. The [join](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/join/) is creating markers for those three types, to customize how CSS will style the display of each edge.
2. In `link`, source and target have special meanings. Each target is drawn with an arrowhead during `path` assignment.